# ORA-00936: missing expression ORACLE please help me

Tags: sql, oracle

help my final project on oracle database.
i'm struggling now.
anyone help me please.

this is my query

```
SELECT tr.id_kasir, 
       tr.tgl_transaksi, 
       sum (
            SELECT CASE tr.id_member when 'M000' 
                   then SUM ( mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) 
                        + SUM(mn.harga_menu*st.qty_menu) * 0.1 
                        - nvl2 ( pro.discount, 
                                       sum(mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * (pro.discount/100),
                                       0) 
                   ELSE SUM(mn.harga_menu*st.qty_menu) 
                        - SUM( mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * 0.05 
                        + SUM(mn.harga_menu*st.qty_menu) * 0.1
                        - nvl2 ( pro.discount, sum(mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * (pro.discount/100) , 0)
                   END Setoran 
           FROM transaksi tr
          join struk st on (st.no_transaksi = tr.no_transaksi) 
          join menu mn on (st.kode_menu = mn.kode_menu )
          left outer join promo pro on (pro.kode_menu = mn.kode_menu)
          GROUP BY tr.id_kasir, tr.tgl_transaksi, tr.id_member,pro.discount 
          ORDER BY tr.tgl_transaksi, tr.id_kasir) setoran 
from transaksi tr 
group by tr.id_kasir, tr.tgl_transaksi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what this query is trying but I see a few issues there. E.g. you can't use the `ORDER BY` inside `SUM()`, you can't use the `SUM` inside `CASE` this way...

Let's try fixing it by breaking the query... start with the inner part. Does the following query work?

```
SELECT Sum( CASE tr.id_member WHEN 'M000' 
                   then ( mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) 
                        +(mn.harga_menu*st.qty_menu) * 0.1 
                        - nvl2 ( pro.discount, 
                                      (mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * (pro.discount/100),
                                       0) 
                   ELSE (mn.harga_menu*st.qty_menu) 
                        - ( mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * 0.05 
                        + (mn.harga_menu*st.qty_menu) * 0.1
                        - nvl2 ( pro.discount, (mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * (pro.discount/100) , 0)
                   ) Setoran 
           FROM transaksi tr
          join struk st on (st.no_transaksi = tr.no_transaksi) 
          join menu mn on (st.kode_menu = mn.kode_menu )
          left outer join promo pro on (pro.kode_menu = mn.kode_menu)
          GROUP BY tr.id_kasir, tr.tgl_transaksi, tr.id_member,pro.discount
```

If the above query works, you can easily wrap it within the outer query.

Comment: hallo hash brown. thankyou or your answer, but the query above isn't working. can i get your contact for more question about the query above ? i guess is hould send you the data set :'(

Comment: the inner query from the prev is working well. the problem is the outer query :'(